# Algorithmic differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, algorithms

If we have function $f(x)=(x+x^2)^2$ we need  fix the dependent variable to be differentiated and computes the derivative with respect to each sub-expression recursively, according to chain rule we have -

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dw_1}\frac{dw_1}{dx}=(\frac{dy}{dw_2}\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}=(((\frac{dy}{dw_4}\frac{dw_4}{dw_3})\frac{dw_3}{dw_2})\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}=((((\frac{dy}{dw_5}\frac{dw_5}{dw_4})\frac{dw_4}{dw_3})\frac{dw_3}{dw_2})\frac{dw_2}{dw_1})\frac{dw_1}{dx}$

$w_1=x$

$w_2=w_1*w_1$

$w_3=w_1+w_2$

$w_4=w_3*w_3$

I am trying to calculate derivative, using REVERSE MODE. But I am obviously have a mistake somewhere -

$\bar w_4=1$

$\bar w_3= \bar w_4 * \frac{dw_4}{dw_3}=2w_3$

$\bar w_2= \bar w_3 * \frac{dw_3}{dw_2}=2w_3$

$\bar w_1= \bar w_2 * \frac{dw_2}{dw_1}+\bar w_3 * \frac{dw_3}{dw_1}=2w_3*2w_1+2w_3*(1+2w_1)=4w_3w_1+2w_3+4w_3w_1$

instead of right derivative - $4w_3w_1+2w_3=4(x+x^2)x+2(x+x^2)=6x^2+4x^3+2x $

Comparing with other results the mistake is $\bar w_1=2w_3*2w_1 \textbf + 2w_3*(1+ \textbf 0)=4w_3w_1+2w_3+2w_3w$ So we are doing only one step in depth.

Now the question is the logic of $\textbf {addition}$ in case of many inputs - i.e. $ \mathbf {4w_3w_1 +2w_3}$? From what rule this addition follows?

Comment: What are the $\bar{w}_k$? Why have you written $\bar{w}_4 = 1$?

Comment: According to the mode, we are taking $\bar f = \bar w_4 =1 $ (seed value)

Comment: For those confused about what the problem is, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation . It's basically computer algebra…

Comment: Of course I went through it and now I think that I know where I did mistake, but It is still not clear why for many inputs we should do addition. It is not mention anywhere - If you know please write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would write $$f'(x)=2(x+x^2)(1+2x)$$

Comment: It is the same thing, I have a mistake somewhere, because for $\bar w_1$ I am receiving another result

Comment: sorry, why do you use such a algorithm?

Comment: My goal is understandanding how Algorithmic differentiation-  in particular reverse mode works)